# Error message when creating an animated QR code with Python

Tags: python, qr-code

I try to create an animiated QR code using the following code:

```
import segno
from urllib.request import urlopen
slts_qrcode = segno.make_qr("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTWKbfoikeg")
nirvana_url = urlopen("https://media.giphy.com/media/LpwBqCorPvZC0/giphy.gif")
slts_qrcode.to_artistic(
    background=nirvana_url,
    target="animated_qrcode.gif",
    scale=5,
)
```

But I only get this error message when running the code:

```
(selenium) C:\DEV\Python-Diverses\Segno>python exmpl2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Python-Diverses\Segno\exmpl2.py", line 6, in <module>
    slts_qrcode.to_artistic(
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\segno\__init__.py", line 972, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError('{0} object has no attribute {1}'
AttributeError: <class 'segno.QRCode'> object has no attribute to_artistic
```

How can I create an animated QR code using Python?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?  Did you `pip install qrcode-artistic`?  The artistic stuff is not part of the base segno library, because it is silly.